# How to display a Bootswatch modal in React?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I'd like to show a modal component when I click a button in React. I followed tutorials but my modal still does not appear.

When I put text in my modal, the text appears when I click, but not if I put the bootswatch component(https://bootswatch.com/lux/).

I imported the two CSS files of the theme:
import '../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/lux/bootstrap.css';
import '../node_modules/bootswatch/dist/lux/bootstrap.min.css';

But not the sccs files because they asked me some problems during the compilation.
This can be the cause of my problem?
All other components are good with just these two files.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from '../pages/home.js';
import Logo from '../img/logo.png';
import ModalLoginRegister from './modalLoginRegister';

export default class Header extends React.Component{
      state = {
        visible: false
      };

      onShow = () => this.setState({ visible: true });
      onHide = () => this.setState({ visible: false });
      render(){
        const { visible } = this.state;
        return (
          <Router>
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
                <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" />
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> TheQuest</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                      <Link class="nav-link" to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <Link class="nav-link" to="/browse">Browse</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <Link class="nav-link" to="/create">Create</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <Link class="nav-link" to="/favorite">Favorite</Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.onShow}>
                      Login / Register
                </button>
                <ModalLoginRegister visible={visible} onHide={this.onHide}/>
            </nav>

            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> 
            <Route path="/browse" component={Browse} />
            <Route path="/create" component={Create} />
            <Route path="/favorite" component={Favorite} />
         </Router>
        );
      }
  }

  function Browse() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Browse</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function Create() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Create</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function Favorite() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Favorite</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class ModalLoginRegister extends React.Component{
    onHide = e => {
        this.props.onHide && this.props.onHide(e);
    };
    render() {
        if(!this.props.visible){
            return null;
        }
        console.log("Show modal test");
        return(

            <div class="modal">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" 
                            onClick={this.onHide}>Close</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I click on my "Login / Registration" button, nothing is displayed. But this message appears on my terminal: "Show modal test".
other than that no error in my terminal

Comment: Use className instead class

Comment: You can try this `{this.state.visible && <ModalLoginRegister onHide={this.onHide}/>}` Remove the `if(!this.props.visible)` condition from your modal component. You don't need to add 2 `CSS` file, you can remove any 1. We just need any 1 of them. Also in React we use `className` instaed of `class`.

Comment: Thanks for your advices ! I changed what you said, my code is cleaner now. Unfortunately my problem is still here.